# ROS2 launch external (non ROS) program

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am looking for a possibility to start a non-ROS program in ROS2 with a launchfile. For ROS1 there is [aliencontrol](https://github.com/acschaefer/aliencontrol).
Is there something like this for ROS2?
Or is it possible to start external programs from the Python launchfile?

Thank you!
Jan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386661/ros2-launch-external-(non-ros)-program/) by [JanWeber](https://answers.ros.org/users/84870/janweber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-09-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the `ExecuteProcess` Action (https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/master/launch/launch/actions/execute_process.py#L89)

In fact, the `Node` Action you're probably already using in the python launch script wraps `ExecuteProcess`.

```
ExecuteProcess(cmd=['ping', '192.168.1.1'],
               output='screen'),
```

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2021-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flo](https://answers.ros.org/users/55147/flo/) on 2021-09-23**:
please consider ticking the answer to be correct if it has solved your problem.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-04-07**:
Concrete example that uses `ExecuteProcessAction` can be found in the official tutorial https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Using-Event-Handlers.html